# Looking for anime about a girl who transforms into an over sexualized woman

Tags: story-identification, anime

I watched this anime when I was very young. There was a guy on a bridge (I think) and it was night time. He sees this innocent looking girl with white and black hair and they talk and then she transforms into this wildly sexual woman. I think he says something like “this is my first time seeing boobs!”

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.